# What are the actions one can do against chess.com players who stop moving when they are in an objectively losing position and refuse to resign?

Tags: online-chess, etiquette

One of my opponents at [chess.com](http://chess.com) just stopped moving after falling into objectively losing position, refused to resign, and made me wait for 20 minutes to claim a win by time.

I've recently resumed my online chess activity and I have experienced this childish behavior of some online chess players several times already.

Does chess.com's engine detect such unsportsmanlike behavior? Or is there a way to flag such users, so that they could be punished? What is the proper etiquette for us to proceed in such cases?

Here's the game position when my opponent stopped moving and refused to resign:

```
[Title "Me vs Malicious Player"]
[FEN "8/7P/2k1p3/p3P3/Pp1K2P1/1P6/8/8 w - - 0 44"]
```

Comment: I usually block them and move on. Not much that you can do except to make sure you never meet them again.

Comment: actually, chess.com should make them forfeit the match after 4 or 5 minutes in a live game. Just wait. That's how it worked a few years ago.

Comment: @Steve, that didn't happen.

Comment: Make food, get water, watch tv, play on computer.

Comment: They should offer a game mode where individual moves have a time limit (in addition to the overall game timer)

Comment: If you don't like your opponent having time on the clock to burn, play shorter games!  I

Comment: @touchmybody I feel like that might punish a few people genuinely trying to think a while on a move. I guess if you both agree to it, that's fine; it just changes the game a fair amount (players would need to avoid being in complicated positions or they'd either get the boot or be forced to make a move prematurely).

Comment: I've had this happen on FICS, including in cases where the opponent in a lost position had only one legal move when he let his time run out.  Attempting to report the incident to FICS elicits this automated response: "While it might be considered bad sportsmanship it is perfectly legal to use all your allocated time. To avoid this player in the future, simply add him to your noplay list. Regards, abuse"

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The behavior you describe is bad sportsmanship and goes against the policies of chess.com. See the [chess.com fair play policy](https://support.chess.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1444922-fair-play-policy) and this [blog post about the new abuse report system](https://www.chess.com/blog/News/new-tools-for-fair-play-on-chess-com) which includes an option specifically for "poor sportsmanship / stalling in games".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have submitted the abuse report. What particularly drove me nuts was the fact that if you look at that user's [profile page](https://www.chess.com/member/johnnynz43), everyone was complaining about his unsportsmanlike behavior.

Comment: But there is no way to prove the player isn’t legimately using those 20 minutes to make a move. They have been given that time and in my opinion rightfully should be allowed to use it. If it bothers the OP, just get away from the keyboard or take a break on another webpage which the other answer suggests.

Comment: The standard of proof is up to chess.com since it's a private website and not a court of law, but let's just say that it is highly suspicious that someone who managed to make 40 moves in 10 min suddenly needs 20 min to ponder one move, especially in such an obviously lost position (there's a mate in 5). And it's not the first time.

Comment: @user1997744 - I'd agree, other than the fact that it doesn't take 20 minutes to realise that black has no chance of winning in this position.  In fact, it doesn't even take 20 seconds.

Comment: @Jules Yes but my point is - like the law itself - having black and white (no pun intended) rules mot subject to interpretation or some human judgement while not always ideal, works fairest in most circumstances. And in this case the opponent has 20 minutes. This case might be obvious but sets a bad precedent for cases where it may not be so obvious.

Comment: @itub Abstratcing from the case at hand - not everybody who can make 40 moves in 10 minutes is able to look-ahead five moves (though in the specific situation, the choices are fairly limited); under the assumption of good faith the opponent might be a beginner trying to find a straw to grab in the form of a possible stalemate (impossible to find here, so despair takes even longer to look). Obviousness is always relative and therefore the whole discussion might be problematic. Should black be obliged to resign after the "obviously" inferior 1. e4 a6, which was but won by black in Karpov-Miles?

Comment: @itub, please update your answer to include [new tools for fair play on Chess.com](https://www.chess.com/blog/News/new-tools-for-fair-play-on-chess-com).

Answer (score 49):

Assuming you also have plenty of time on your clock, **make a break**: have a drink, or check your mail, or pay a visit to the bathroom, or grab a book (even if it's an openings book, it doesn't count at cheating in that position ;) ), or go verify if your baby hasn't hurt herself with that knife she was trying to grab when you were too busy calculating your Bxh6! sacrifice to stop her. 
Meanwhile, check every five minutes that the opponent hasn't played (the worst trick would be if he plays a meaningless move at some point and ends up winning on time). After your well-deserved 20' pause, collect your point, block this undelicate opponent to make sure you never play against him anymore, and look for another partner. You will win the next game as well thanks to your fresh mind after the 20' break.

In case you're a real chess lover who doesn't care about his virtual Elo rating, and really just want to start a new game as soon as possible, **the alternative** is to resign yourself. I almost never do that because I *do* care about my little rating points (*vanitas vanitatum, omnia vanitas*) and because the pueril opponent might believe he has been smart when he gets gifted that pseudo-win, which might even encourage him to continue his misbehavour. But objectively, we shouldn't care at all what the abusing, unfair player is thinking - It's not our job to educate him, and we don't have the means to do it anyway.

Comment: All good but the game took place very late during the night and I wanted to go to sleep.

Comment: @gdrt : annoying indeed. Well, go brush your teeth, wear pajamas, and check just before falling asleep that the opponent still hasn't played...

Comment: Since you care so much about your fake internet points, here, have 10 more :) (although, full disclosure, the upvote was more for the rest of the answer than that line)

Comment: I believe resigning in a won position is against Chess.com rules, and I would strongly advice against that. I wouldn't want to play against someone who's actually a lot stronger than me but happens to be underrated because they like resigning to be able to start the next game faster.

Answer (score 21):

I followed [@itub](https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/21240/16057)'s suggestion and [filed a report](https://support.chess.com/customer/portal/emails/new) against the particular user. Here's the answer I got from Chess.com support:

> [...]
>
> Certainly, this is not what we want on our site! I have sent this
>   member to our investigative department for a close watch on this
>   account. They will be monitored and if they continue this behavior, we
>   will have to close their account!
>
> Thank you so much for reporting! We appreciate it so much!!
>
> [...]
>
> Chess.com Member Support Staff

Since Chess.com also takes it seriously, I do suggest to report malicious users instead of not doing anything, so that in future they don't ruin online chess experience of your fellow mates as well.

Answer (score 5):

Pre-move

h8Q 
Qh7
 g5
g6
g7
g8Q
Qhf7
Qxe6
 Qgf7
 Qee8++

and go to sleep. Then file a complaint in the morning.

Comment: You can do that many premoves at once?

Comment: https://support.chess.com/customer/portal/articles/1444864-what-are-premoves-and-how-do-they-work- says there's a limit of 5.

Comment: Hmm, I guess I shouldn't trust random people on the internet: https://lichess.org/forum/lichess-feedback/multiple-premoves Would it be wrong to write a bot for the sole purpose of implementing infinite pre-moves?

Comment: @Acccumulation Possibly. You'd have to look at chess.com's TOS.

Comment: While it is still two premoves over the limit, I just want to point out that if g8Q in the sequence above is not checkmate then following with Qxe6 instead of Qhf7 definitely will be. Slightly closer!

Answer (score 4):

Time for an update: Chess.com has just [released](https://www.chess.com/blog/News/new-tools-for-fair-play-on-chess-com) a new formular for reporting abusing players.

It includes a category "poor sportsmanship / stalling in games" that totally fits your situation.

Comment: Thank you! I've upvoted this answer of yours and suggested this as an update to the previously accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't much you can do to make the game end immediately. If you care about your online rating and don't want to do something like offer a draw, you'll have to wait. I'd suggest doing something else that you need to do with that time.

After the game though, there is plenty you can do. The best course of action would be reporting the user to Chess.com, explaining how they made you wait 20 mins. For proof, you could take a screenshot of your game when your opponent has 15 minutes, and another screenshot when he runs out of time. This will show Chess.com it is the same position, and that your opponent just let the clock run down.

Additionally, you can block the user so that you never play them again. This will save you some time in the future, if you get paired again.

Here's Chess.com's link on how to deal with unfair players. They give instructions on how to report a player, as well as other things:

https://support.chess.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1444879-fair-play-on-chess-com-what-you-need-to-know